# how to pass model from view to controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc i am trying to pass model into controller from view

This is my view

[image: View]

My Control

[image: Controller]

but while debugging im getting all null values

[image]

i am using view model 
[image]

where i am doing mistake
Help me 
thanks

Comment: Are all the properties of `UserInfo` represented as form data in your form? If not, then the model binder will insert nulls when trying to construct the `UserInfo` object from the posted form data. (Also, you have a *list* of drop-down lists?!!)

Comment: You need to show your code, not an image of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an ActionLink to post a form. Have a look at this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios)

```
@model YourViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  Model NAme : @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  <input type="submit" value="Post to server" />
}
```

Comment: now i am try using  <form action="/User/AddUser2" method="post"></form> but still action is not calling (its not hitting break point )

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use an "ActionLink" to call the "AddUser2" method controller. An ActionLink generates a basic link which redirects to the controller passed in parameter.

You need to post the form (to send values typed by the user to the controller), not redirect.

To post the form, use the following html tag (instead of the ActionLink) :

```
<input type="submit" value="ok" />
```

This code generate a button, which will send your form when user will click on it.